# How do I debug CURL error 56 on API endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, php-curl

I have a WordPress installation that uses .NET APIs hosted on another server. Lately, I was facing this issue where my WordPress installation on Apache/Linux was constantly receiving CURL error 56 on a few endpoints. After much failed debugging, I moved to Windows/IIS environment where everything worked fine.

Now, all of a sudden, I have started receiving same error on Windows/IIS as well. The mind-boggling part is that the external APIs I'm calling are hosted on the same server. But among them, a few are working fine and other are giving CURL error 56.

So for example, if I call:

```
https://example.com/api/v5/Members/SignIn
```

This works fine. But when I call:

```
https://example.com/api/v5/Members/VerifyDuplicateAccount
```

It end up abruptly with CURL erro code 56. The error message that I get from `curl_error` is as follows:

```
OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
```

I have wasted days figuring out the issue but have failed. I have tried updating php_curl to 7.6.8, updated PHP to 7.4.4 but nothing has helped so far.

Here is a test script I have written for debugging:

```
    <?php
        ob_start();  
        $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        $_headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Authorization: Bearer 5579PP5HSfZXjWZ9kpqEn9ST7BaWhTrcEUghL7Z_sRpGKXTmh40WxdfJ-9F7pe5LwHY9w0DH6v8r7HQrNke3JjonWwFRwTV-_8JEUuwudrKf6Ii1QSTGWtkaZ_GRZVWbN8eUh5BzPnRnzF8JQ_Goq_dx0cXQYqewQHG7iAU1aSifatwbAZLY-h_GGBTnJ72uZ6ZNix8E-7Th4Pftrpqx5bytay0fY1ES5ppuqDn4h-9TakZEedwnpzup30ApphTGGQxYAGrkRArEj0nXXV2yH8lHUL8SrZJKc9SGaE8y6qtxQc_F50imU-f8fb5P2WSNaPeYEaYJ2o6dj1r7A9VuiabCxMsdAzIFvlyPSrcdpGO1uBRoTVwVBMmH7prpFRzKWYrX69BF-IET4rN8POT1Zg',
          'Expect: '
        ); //print_r($_headers);
        $params = '{"OwnerDescription":"myOwner","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/80.0.3987.149 Safari\/537.36","VendorKey":"abc123","address":{"HomeAddress":{"CountryCode":"US","StateProvinceAbbrevation":"GA","Line1":"Test ADDRESS","City":"ATL","PostalCode":"30003"},"MailingAddress":{"CountryCode":"US","StateProvinceAbbrevation":"GA","Line1":"Test ADDRESS","City":"ATL","PostalCode":"30003"},"BillingAddress":{"CountryCode":"US"}},"contactInfo":{"PrimaryContactNumber":"1234334444","Email":"xyzm@gmail.com"},"membership":{"Members":[{"FirstName":"Osama","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Trankler","ParticipantType":"Primary","Gender":"NotAvailable","DateOfBirth":"11\/12\/1998"}],"EffectiveDate":"04\/08\/2020","Term":null,"TermLength":null,"PlanName":"ABC"}}';
        $curl = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://example.com/api/v5/Members/VerifyDuplicateAccount';
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $_headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
        if ($response = curl_exec($curl)) {
        } else {
          $response = curl_error($curl);
        }
        echo 'curl_error=>'.curl_errno($curl);
        @curl_close($curl);
        fclose($out);  
        $debug = ob_get_clean();
        echo 'debug=> '.$debug;
        print_r($response);

    ?>
```

And here is the response I get:

```
    * Trying 199.1.1.1:443...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to example.com (199.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
    * ALPN, offering h2
    * ALPN, offering http/1.1
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: C:\curl_cert\cacert.pem
      CApath: none
    * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
    * Server certificate:
    *  subject: C=US; ST=Texas; L=Lewisville; O=ABC Holdings LLC
    T; CN=*.example.com
    *  start date: Nov 13 00:00:00 2019 GMT
    *  expire date: Nov 17 12:00:00 2021 GMT
    *  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Hig
    rance Server CA
    *  SSL certificate verify ok.
    > PUT /api/v5/Members/VerifyDuplicateAccount HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer 5579PP5HSfZX
    Content-Length: 1023

    * upload completely sent off: 1023 out of 1023 bytes
    * OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
    * Closing connection 0
    debug=> curl_error=>56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
```